# Why am I getting "Input string was not in a correct format" here?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I solve the Input string error occurring in the following line:

```
 string body = String.Format(
     "The following leave request was made by user {o}: \n Date: {1} \t Hours: {2} \t Reason: {3}", 
     username.ToString(), 
     TxtBoxDate.Text,
     DDHours.SelectedValue+DDTimeWindow.SelectedValue, 
     TxtNotes.Text);
```

Comment: mark answered please to stop answers rolling in :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a typo in your code.


Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you have the letter `o` instead of a zero `0`. Try:

```
string body = String.Format("The following leave request was made by user {0}: \n Date: {1} \t Hours: {2} \t Reason: {3}", username.ToString(), TxtBoxDate.Text, DDHours.SelectedValue+DDTimeWindow.SelectedValue, TxtNotes.Text);
```

Comment: Oh how stupid of me. THanks :)

Answer (score 2):

simple typo, you have used `o` instead of `0`

Answer (score 2):

Just change the 'o' to a '0' (zero).

Answer (score 2):

You have an O instead of a zero `{o}` -> `{0}`

```
    string body =
        String.Format(
            "The following leave request was made by user {0}: \n Date: {1} \t Hours: {2} \t Reason: {3}",
            username.ToString(), 
            TxtBoxDate.Text, 
            DDHours.SelectedValue + DDTimeWindow.SelectedValue,
            TxtNotes.Text);
```